# Weird lines on side faces of a cube

Tags: modeling, texturing

How do I fix theese weird lines? I'm new to blender and i can't find anything about it anywhere.

[image: Weird lines]

Comment: Read about texture mapping.

Comment: Your uv is stretched, did you extrude Simple plain? You need unwrap uv once again for those sides

Comment: @MikoCG i used the example cube. I unwraped it and nothing changed.

Comment: once you've unwrapped you need to use the UV output of the Texture Coordinate node in the Shader Editor

Comment: This would be a long answer to explain basics of uv unwrapping... The reason why your texture is stretched is because your uv is wrong, open your uv editing, select all your faces... Do you see 6 faces in your uv? If not and you only see one, your uv is incorrect

Comment: @moonboots thanks! it worked

Answer (score 3):

As MikoCG says, you need to unwrap your cube. Once you've unwrapped you need to use the *UV* output of the *Texture Coordinate* node in the *Shader Editor*:

[image]